# SSRS (reporting services) deploy

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I deployed my report into the local server but when I click to open it then gives me the following error. Do u have any idea to overcome this issue?

```
       •    An error occurred during client rendering. 
       o    An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 
           Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.
                (rsErrorOpeningConnection) 
           The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write 
               to the file 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\okul.accdb'. 
               It is already opened exclusively by another user, 
               or you need permission to view and write its data.
```

Comment: According to your error message it looks like you are facing concurrent or permission issue. Did you check the permission for the file C:\Users\USER\Desktop\okul.accdb  ?

Comment: @eestein yes i have checked. Anyway i am using with admin account.

Comment: I get it, and you have the account NETWORK SERVICE with modify permission set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try checking if the account used by SSRS has the modify permission on that file folder.

You can do that through RSCM (Reporting Services Configuration Manager).
You can even add a local admin account if that's a dev machine.
Click on `"Service Account"` and configure it your way.

Should you need, here's more detailed information on how to do that:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522727(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: may I use another user interface for reporting? For example, I did't like the normal interface of reports where are already deployed. I deployed 10 reports into the our test database. But I must use my admin account to reach these reports. How can other employees reach these reports without admin account?

Comment: @Omnipotent you can achieve that by giving the correct permissions to your network service account. That account should have modify permission on your files' folder.